# Dynamic Multi-row INSERT in SQLite with SELECT

Tags: sqlite

I have a static table called SSJ which looks like:

```
ID   fSSID        tSSID
1    30000002     30000005
2    30000002     30002973
3    30000003     30000001
```

I'm trying to INSERT into a separate table tmpTable based on a SELECT for fSSID from SSJ. tmpTable has the structure:

```
id INTEGER, ssid NUM, wt NUM, prnt NUM
```

The insert I'm using looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO tmpTable (ssid, wt, prnt) VALUES ((SELECT tSSID FROM SSJ WHERE fSSID=30000002), 0, 30000002)
```

With this INSERT I'm expecting to see two new rows in tmpTable because the SELECT should garner two results from SSJ, id's 1 and 2, but I'm only getting one. This is only a minor example as in the actual SSJ table there could be many multiples of the same fSSID (or there could be only 1).

What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With INSERT...VALUES..., you get exactly as many rows as you have written into the VALUES clause. A subquery used in place of an expression is a [scalar subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#in_op), i.e., only the first result is used.

To insert a dynamic number of rows, you must use the SELECT form of the [INSERT statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html):

```
INSERT INTO tmpTable (ssid, wt, prnt)
SELECT tSSID, 0, fSSID
FROM SSJ
WHERE fSSID=30000002;
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh, there we go. Now works as expected. Thank you CL.